# How to Custom 404 Page Not Found in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I just learn CodeIgniter 4 Framework. How to customize my 404 page not found?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your Routes.php file and find

```
$routes->set404Override();
```

Now , If you want to display just an error message then write

```
    $routes->set404Override(function(){
    echo "your error message";
});
```

instead of

```
$routes->set404Override();
```

Or 
If you want to return a view then write like below:

```
$routes->set404Override(function(){
    return view('your_filename');
});
```

instead of

```
$routes->set404Override();
```

Answer (score 1):

// Would execute the show404 method of the App\Errors class

```
$routes->set404Override('App\Errors::show404');
```

// Will display a custom view

```
$routes->set404Override(function()
{
    echo view('my_errors/not_found.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize your 404 page, modify `app/Views/errors/html/error_404.php` to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

For custom error messages

in Config\routes.php

```
// Custom 404 view with error message.
$routes->set404Override(function( $message = null )
{
    $data = [
        'title' => '404 - Page not found',
        'message' => $message,
    ];
    echo view('my404/viewfile', $data);
});
```

in my viewfile, to display error:

```
<?php if (! empty($message) && $message !== '(null)') : ?>
  <?= esc($message) ?>
<?php else : ?>
  Sorry! Cannot seem to find the page you were looking for.
<?php endif ?>
```

from my controller:

```
throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException('This is my custom error message');
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Christianto answer, in 4.3.7 at least I had to enter the full namespace path, when using a controller method to override 404.

```
// In Routes.php (full path)
$routes->set404Override('\App\Controllers\Start::pageNotFound');

// In the controller
public function pageNotFound() {
    return $this->view('error_404');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit config file **App/Config/Routing.php** find variable **$override404** and provide the path to your 404 error method controller.

```
public ?string $override404 = '\App\Controllers\PagesStatusCode::pageNotFound';
```

And add controller **PagesStatusCode.php**

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class PagesStatusCode extends BaseController 
{
 public function pageNotFound()
 {         
    $this->response->setStatusCode(404);
    $data['message'] = "Page not found";
    return view('errors/html/error_404', $data);  
 }
}
```

And add an error view file template **App/Views/errors/html/error_404.php**, with custom html layout and css styling.

---

Or another implementation method:

1. Create a Controller Method

   ```
   namespace App\Controllers;

   class PagesStatusCode extends BaseController 
   {
    public function pageNotFound()
    {         
     $this->response->setStatusCode(404);
     $data['message'] = "Page not found";
     return view('errors/html/error_404', $data);  
    }
   }
   ```
2. Create a Page Not Found View (error_404.php):

   echo $message;
3. Configure Routes with:

   routes->get('404', 'PagesStatusCode::pageNotFound');